# Why can't I scroll on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am on a Chromebook and I can't scroll on my web page. I don't have any other device to test it on so maybe it's just the Chromebook. My code is below. Click the contact me button that's where the problem is. You might have to copy and paste the code in your editor because the preview on SO is small.

```js
function contact_anim() {
  $('#links-div').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("#contact-form").fadeIn();
  });
}

function cancel_contact_anim() {
  $('#contact-form').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#links-div').fadeIn();
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url('amsterdam1920x1080.jpg');
  background-size: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(252, 0, 0, 0.67);
}

#links-div {
  margin: 50px;
}

.links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 8px solid white;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

p {
  font-size: 27px;
}

.links:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="text"], #msg {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#msg {
  height: 225px;
}

#contact-form {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>j0rdan.me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <h1>j0rdan.me</h1>
      <p>This site is currently in the making, but<br>feel free to take a look around</p>
      <div id="links-div">
        <a href="#" id="about" class="links">ABOUT ME</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="#" id="contact" class="links" onclick="contact_anim()">CONTACT ME</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="#" id="projects" class="links">MY PROJECTS</a><br/><br/>
      </div>

      <form id="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post" style="display: none">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br/>
        <textarea id="msg"></textarea><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <button type="submit" id="send" name="send">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="animation_handlers.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can create a codepen and post a link on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `overflow-y: scroll` to your `#main` rule. The `fixed` position is making it non-scrollable:

```js
function contact_anim() {
  $('#links-div').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("#contact-form").fadeIn();
  });
}

function cancel_contact_anim() {
  $('#contact-form').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#links-div').fadeIn();
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url('amsterdam1920x1080.jpg');
  background-size: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(252, 0, 0, 0.67);
}

#links-div {
  margin: 50px;
}

.links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 8px solid white;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

p {
  font-size: 27px;
}

.links:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="text"], #msg {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#msg {
  height: 225px;
}

#contact-form {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>j0rdan.me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <h1>j0rdan.me</h1>
      <p>This site is currently in the making, but<br>feel free to take a look around</p>
      <div id="links-div">
        <a href="#" id="about" class="links">ABOUT ME</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="#" id="contact" class="links" onclick="contact_anim()">CONTACT ME</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="#" id="projects" class="links">MY PROJECTS</a><br/><br/>
      </div>

      <form id="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post" style="display: none">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br/>
        <textarea id="msg"></textarea><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <button type="submit" id="send" name="send">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="animation_handlers.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say